# Join a table with CriteriaBuilder and an additional parameter seems to have no effect

Tags: java, sql, jpa, left-join, criteria-api

I have two entities that are structured as follows

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Person")
public class Person {

   @EmbeddedId
   private PrimaryKey personPK = new PrimaryKey();

   @Column(name = "name")
   private String name;

   @Column(name = "lastname")
   private String lastname;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "books")
   private Set<Books> books = new HashSet<>();
}

@Embeddable
public class PrimaryKey {

   @Column(name = "ID")
   private long id;

   @Column(name = "SOCIALNUMBER"
   private String socialNumber;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Books")
public class Books {

   @EmbeddedId
   private PrimaryKeyBooks booksPK = new PrimaryKeyBooks();

   @MapsId("personPK")
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name = "ID", referencedColumnName = "ID"), @JoinColumn(name = "SOCIALNUMBER",
        referencedColumnName = "SOCIALNUMBER") })
   private Person person;

   @Column(name = "title")
   private String title;

   @Column(name = "publisher")
   private String publisher;

   @Column(name = "isListed")
   private Boolean isListed;
}
```

PrimaryKey and PrimaryKeyBooks has the same attributes.

The attribute "isListed" could be true or false. Now I want a query that returns all persons. But the list of books should only be filled if the attribute "isListed" is true. Otherwise the list should be null.
The SQL query I want is this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM Person t1 
left join books t2 on t1.id = t2.id and t1.socialNumber = t2.socialNumber 
and t2.isListed = true;
```

This query works exactly as I want it to.
Now I want the same with the Criteria API. What I try is this:

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Person> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Person.class);
Root<Person> personRoot = query.from(Person.class);
        
Join<Person, Books> join = personRoot.join(Person_.books, JoinType.LEFT);
join.on(criteriaBuilder.equal(join.get(Books_.isListed), true));
                
return entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList()
```

But it looks like the additional parameter in the on function is ignored. As a result, I also get the people who have books whose isListed value is set to false.
Could it be a problem, that the on function and the @JoinColumn annotation is not usable at the same time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problems with INNER JOIN and LEFT/RIGHT OUTER JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16442900/problems-with-inner-join-and-left-right-outer-join)

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: You are not translating the LEFT JOIN ON AND properly. LEFT JOIN returns INNER JOIN rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN. After a LEFT JOIN a WHERE, INNER JOIN or HAVING that requires a right [sic] table column to be not NULL removes any rows with introduced NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN rows, ie "turns OUTER JOIN into INNER JOIN". You have that. PS This is a faq. But one must pin down via a [mre] & write many clear, concise & precise phrasings of one's question/problem/goal to search reasonably.

Comment: [Is it true that using INNER JOIN after any OUTER JOIN will essentially invalidate the effects of OUTER JOIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55111083/3404097)